# Group by field name

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to do Group by by City but this possibility doesn't shows up. where is my mistake? there is field city in python file and it's showing up in tree view but not really in Group by

```
<openerp>
    <data>

    <record id="vpicktree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Picking tree city</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="location_dest_id" position="after">
                    <field name="city"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>

       <record model="ir.ui.view" id="stock_picking_filter_city_search">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.tree.filter_search</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="City">
                    <filter name="city" string="City" context="{'group_by':'city'}"/>
                 </search>
             </field>
       </record>

        <record id="action_picking_tree_city" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">City</field>
            <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,calendar</field>
            <field name="domain"></field>
            <field name="context">{ 'group_by':'city' }</field>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="stock.view_picking_internal_search"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group by must be in search view not on the action setion as you did, so you have to edit your search view:

```
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="stock_picking_filter_city_search">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.tree.filter_search</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="City">
                <filter name="city" string="City" context="{'group_by':'city'}"/>


                <group expand="0" string="Grouper par">
                    <filter string="City" icon="terp-personal" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'city'}"/>
                </group>

             </search>
         </field>
   </record>
```